# Understanding the Definition of minimal prime ideal of a graded module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading algebraic geometry from Robin Hartshorne. He has used a term "$p$ is a minimal prime of a graded $S$ module $M$". What does it mean? I know the definition of minimal prime over an ideal.

Comment: Probably a prime minimal over the annihilator of $M$. Hopefully $M$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Ok but if it is defined in this way . Then what is the motivation behind it.

Comment: Yes It is a finitely generated module.

Comment: If $M$ is finitely generated, the support of $M$ is precisely $\mathcal V(\operatorname{Ann} M)$, i.e. a minimal prime over the annihilator is a minimal prime of the support, i.e. corresponds to an irreducible component if the support.

Comment: Read on page 50 of the book what the author means by a minimal prime of M.